# jquery hide-show content onclick- cleaner code

Tags: jquery

Basically, what i want is when you click on a certain element(ex: #click1 #click2 #click3), a certain div becomes visible. When you click on another element, another div shows up but it hides the previous one and so on. I already have the code working but it feels like i'm repeating myself too much. I mean what if there were, like, 15 elements that would show different content onClick? Is there a cleaner way to do this? Link to [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4v20u8bn/).
Code:

```
//html
<ul>
    <li id="click1">A</li>
    <li id="click2">B</li>
    <li id="click3">C</li>
</ul>
<div class="DIV1">BLA</div>
<div class="DIV2">BLA</div>
<div class="DIV3">BLA</div>


//JS
 $(".DIV1, .DIV2, .DIV3").addClass("hide");
$("#click1").click(function () {
    $(".DIV1").show();
    $(".DIV2 ,.DIV3").hide();
});
$("#click2").click(function () {
    $(".DIV2").show();
    $(".DIV1,.DIV3").hide();
});
$("#click3").click(function () {
    $(".DIV3").show();
    $(".DIV1,.DIV2").hide();
});
```

Comment: You could add more than one class name to your element, so maybe you could group them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most basic way to do this:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $('div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4v20u8bn/1/)**

Now of course, this would have issues given other lists and divs in your page, and the workaround for that is to just wrap the block of lists/divs you want to target in an element (e.g. a div) with a easily selectable identifier like a class or ID. But since you gave a basic code example, I gave you a simple solution ;)

Comment: No, it's perfect for what i need. I knew there had to be a smarter way :) Thank you